# How to cluster elements based on minimum distance threshold in matrix using R?

Tags: r, matrix, cluster-computing, distance-matrix

I have distance matrix `mdist` (187x187 items). I need to have clusters based on minimum for each item. I've counted those minimae:

```
mins = list()
for (i in (1:nrow(mdist))) {
  md = min(mdist[i,-c(i)])
  mins <- rbind.data.frame(mins, list(id=i, dist=md))
}
```

When I check the maximum overall `max(mins$dist)` it's 4.

Now I expect to get groups of those items in clusters. While I set the threshold to 5 I expect to get one cluster.

```
hc <- hclust(as.dist(mdist), method="complete")
x <- cutree(hc, h=5)
```

but when I apply `length(unique(x))` it takes 103 clusters.

I guess I do wrong method or what? How to force cluster numbers below the maximum value of such matrix?

Comment: You are assuming that the height measure is directly related to the distribution of minimum distances in a row of the distance matrix. As the documentation for hclust says "the value of the criterion associated with the clustering method for the particular agglomeration." Complete linkage focuses on minimizing the maximum distances between members of a cluster. You can print out the height values as hc$height. If you want a particular number of clusters use the k= argument to cutree() instead of the h= argument.